# Add argument checking to dataclass

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I've defined a dataclass but want to check the values passed and raise an error if some condition is true. This is an example:

```
@dataclass
class my_dataclass():
    some_arg: str

    if self.some_arg not in ('valid1', 'valid2'):
        raise ValueError(f"Value {self.some_arg} not recognized")

    def some_method(self):
        return something
```

This example is wrong, because I can not access `self.some_arg` to do the value checking.

What would be the proper way to do this? Should I define a method to handle this type of check?